# How can json with variable jquery wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm having a problem with passing variables in PHP to jQuery via AJAX.

My code PHP is:

```
    function obtieneurl($args, $instance){
    extract( $args );
    $valorjson = apply_filters('', $instance['value']);

        $variableurl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=".$valorjson;

        return $variableurl;

    }
```

File `Weather-ajax-js.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  

    jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'json',
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data:{
                'action':'obtieneurl'
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                alert('error');
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });


});
```

What is the problem?

Comment: who knows what the problem is

Comment: @No1_Melman no body, I think .......

Answer (score 0):

the function needs to be changed to receive the data from ajax as data is not passed to the function arguments.

```
function obtieneurl(){
$args= $_POST['action']; // or whatever your method is in your ajax call 
extract( $args );
$valorjson = apply_filters('', $instance['value']);

    $variableurl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=".$valorjson;

    return $variableurl;

}
```